# How can i read the URL in an async method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await, microsoft-identity-platform

I have a multi-tenant site in which the database is identified from a resource file using the sub-domain of the URL. I have recently changed the authentication mechanism to Microsoft Identity. The problem is that HttpContext.Current is always null which is expected as the method is async. Is there a way to retrieve Url in this scenario?

Comment: `The problem is that HttpContext.Current is always null which is expected as the method is async`  If you don't use `ConfigureAwait(false)`, the HttpContext will be available in async calls

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I am not using ConfigureAwait(false). HttpContext.Current is null anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Something on your code is preventing the execution from getting back to the synchronization context. You can track that by checking [`SynchronizationContext.Current`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.current).

But you shouldn't be accessing `HttpContext.Current` anyway. It's a bad pattern to rely on singletons like that.

Just write your APIs to depend on values. If you need the URL, pass it as an argument.

Comment: Context like this is what I like to call "sniper code". Code 10 miles away from the code you're currently writing or debugging is having an impact on it, and you have no way of spotting it or why that is. Pass required information as parameters, don't rely on "static" (or thread-static or task-static) context like this.

Comment: Yes, thank you. My initial problem was I had DB calls from UserStore in which the context is null. I have passed the OwinContext from IdentityConfig which seems to do the trick!